# How to add two arrays with different size of elements in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

```
   var firstArray = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
   var secondArray = new int[] { 4, 5, 6, 5, 9, 10};
   var sum = Enumerable.Zip(first, second, (a, b) => a + b);
```

I want the sum to be [5, 7, 9, **5 , 9 , 10**] since firstArray only have 3 elements. Any workaround? Would be better if I am using for loop for this?

Comment: Well, a loop _would_ almost certainly be more readable.  But you know that `.Zip` will return a sequence with a length matching the shortest sequence you provided it.  So it seems rather elementary to me to just `.Concat` the rest via `.Skip()` with the length of the shorter array.

Comment: Alternatively, you could create your own variant of a `.Zip` function that returns elements from the array when the other sequence has run out of elements.  Perhaps that would be an interesting exercise for you to learn about extension methods.